# Как преобразовать HTML в словарь?

Tags: php, html

Имеется DOM-дерево

```
<div itemprop="description" property="v:description">
  <span class="gray">Вид:</span>
  Черный
  <br>
  <span class="gray">Вид заварки:</span>
    В пакетиках
  <br>
  <span class="gray">Вес:</span>
    20*1.5г
  <br>
  <span class="gray">Страна:</span>
    Россия
  <br>
</div>
```

Необходимо собрать информацию в виде

```
 $data = [
  'Вид:' => 'Черный',
  .....
]
```

Comment: что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: возьмите xpath `//*[self::div or self::span]/text()` и вы получите практически ваш результат

Comment: @splash58
так от это и не получается, со span
данные получить не беда а от как текст с привяской к тому значени что в span

Comment: в Simple HTML DOM Parser xpath можно сказать, что и не работает. А, может, другой парсер?

Comment: @splash58 
мне надо масив собрать
от то что в span за ключ, текст что ниже тоесть за спан как згначение
и все что надо

Comment: парсер тебе выдаст текст дива только целиком.а  xpath по мере обработки. Ща попробую ответ сформулировать

Comment: какая версия php ?

Comment: 5.4 +
версия php

Comment: вся соль в том что не могу привязать оно значение к другому
тоесть все что в спане я могу выбрать через цикл 
а от подтянуть то что между тегами спан никак

Comment: я ответ написал, посмотри

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если попробовать без дополнительных библиотек? [Пример в песочнице](http://ideone.com/q7UrNW)

```
<?php
$html = '<div itemprop="description" property="v:description">
  <span class="gray">Вид:</span>
  Черный
  <br>
  <span class="gray">Вид заварки:</span>
    В пакетиках
  <br>
  <span class="gray">Вес:</span>
    20*1.5г
  <br>
  <span class="gray">Страна:</span>
    Россия
  <br>
</div>';

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$spans = $xpath->query("//span[contains(@class, 'gray')]");
$arr = [];
foreach($spans as $span){
    $arr[$span->nodeValue] = trim($span->nextSibling->nodeValue);
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое
парсер использую впервые

Comment: написали бы чуть пораньше :) Мне так лень было комп заводить. а на телефоне писать - жесть :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$str = '<div itemprop="description" property="v:description">
  <span class="gray">Вид:</span>
  Черный
  <br>
  <span class="gray">Вид заварки:</span>
    В пакетиках
  <br>
  <span class="gray">Вес:</span>
    20*1.5г
  <br>
  <span class="gray">Страна:</span>
    Россия
  <br>
</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
// чтобы работало с utf8 добавим заголовок
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $str);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*[self::div or self::span]/text()");
```

xpath вепнул все, что нам нужно

```
Text=''
Text='Вид:'
Text='Черный'
Text=''
Text='Вид заварки:'
Text='В пакетиках'
Text=''
Text='Вес:'
Text='20*1.5г'
Text=''
Text='Страна:'
Text='Россия'
Text=''
```

Теперь будем собирать в нужный формат

```
foreach($elements as $text)
   if (!empty(trim($text->wholeText))) $arr[] = trim($text->wholeText);
print_r($arr);
```

Вот тут уже так

```
Array
    [0] => Вид:
    [1] => Черный
    [2] => Вид заварки:
    [3] => В пакетиках
    [4] => Вес:
    [5] => 20*1.5г
    [6] => Страна:
    [7] => Россия
```

Остались сущие пустяки

```
$res = array();
foreach(array_chunk($arr, 2) as $item) 
 $res[trim($item[0], ':')] = $item[1];

print_r($res);
```

Результат

```
[Вид] => Черный
[Вид заварки] => В пакетиках
[Вес] => 20*1.5г
[Страна] => Россия
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас изучу это все

Comment: Больше чем надо, 
я почти никогда не работал с DOM
тому и вопросы
СПС огромнишее

Comment: Удачи! он часто гораздо удобнее, чем Simple HTML DOM Parser